# How to get a specific date of next month? (Java 8)

Tags: date, java-8, localdatetime, date-manipulation

With today's date, I should get the 16th date of next month.

For example, on passing 13-12-2021, I should get 16-01-2022.

I need to get the next month 16th day from current date (input date). Examples:

- On passing 13-11-2021 should get 16-12-2021.
- On passing 14-11-2021 should get 16-12-2021.
- On passing 15-11-2021 should get 16-12-2021.
- On passing 02-12-2021 should get 16-01-2022.
- On passing 03-12-2021 should get 16-01-2022.
- On passing 03-01-2022 should get 16-02-2022.
- On passing 04-01-2022 should get 16-02-2022.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What did your search turn up? If you can’t find the exact same question, I am sure you can find pieces that you can piece together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time

One of the many strong points of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is date arithmetic like this.

```
public static LocalDate nthDayOfFollowingMonth(
        int desiredDayOfMonth, LocalDate currentDate) {
    return YearMonth.from(currentDate)
            .plusMonths(1)
            .atDay(desiredDayOfMonth);
}
```

Try it out with your example date:

```
    System.out.println(nthDayOfFollowingMonth(
            16, LocalDate.of(2021, Month.DECEMBER, 13)));
```

Output:

> 2022-01-16

We might not have needed to convert to `YearMonth` and back to `LocalDate`. Doing so relieves both me and the reader of considering what happens if today’s day of month doesn’t exist in next month — for example if current date is 30 January (there is no 30 February). What one still wants to consider is what happens if you *request* a day of month tht doesn’t exist next month. For example on 13 January asking for the 30th of next month. We can try that out too:

```
    System.out.println(nthDayOfFollowingMonth(
            30, LocalDate.of(2022, Month.JANUARY, 13)));
```

I find the result very reasonable:

> java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'